# How about a blog and some Jeopardy questions?

Tags: discussion, beta

I occasionally drop in on B&CG SE for a look around as its something that I enjoy reading, but I'm a bit of a fringe user in the real world so don't have anything worthwhile to ask.

However, I've seen a few people mention in comments etc. that this site is not doing well in Beta etc.

From what I've seen in the past the SE folks only close down proposals if visitors don't get good quality answers for their questions. Which I think this site definitely checks the box.

I've watched two other beta sites: fitness and onstartups slowly build up to good quality sites with good traffic. They were both in similar circumstances to this site with low level traffic and questions per day. But they have managed to increase their traffic to decent levels by the hard work of core members and persistence by providing quality answers to the few questions they were getting per day.

Your average user can help by giving a pat on the back to the core group by regularly voting.

But I'd also like to suggest that this site would do well with a blog like some of the other sites (e.g. fitness). It's something that I'd definitely be interested to read. You could cover rules, reviews and recommendations etc.

Jeopardy style questions can also be a boost if chosen carefully and if they are full of solid advice. This is something worth considering.

Keep persisting, I think this site provides great answers and has a good standard.